# Why the last record of table is not fetch in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from two tables names as

> 1.TICKET_MESSAGE_TABLE
>
> 2.TICKET_ATTACHMENT_TABLE

**Query is below**

```
$sql='SELECT msg.*, count(attach_id) as attachments  
      FROM '.TICKET_MESSAGE_TABLE.' msg '.
        ' LEFT JOIN '.TICKET_ATTACHMENT_TABLE.' attach ON  msg.ticket_id=attach.ticket_id 
                    AND msg.msg_id=attach.ref_id '.
    ' WHERE  msg.ticket_id='.db_input($this->getId()).
    ' GROUP BY msg.msg_id 
      ORDER BY msg.created desc';

$msgres=db_query($sql);
      
return $msgres;
```

The problem is the last record from the table TICKET_MESSAGE_TABLE is not fetching until we not insert the new record in this table.
Can any one have idea of this problem. Please.

Comment: What does `db_query()` do. Likely the error is in there

Comment: When i do  ORDER BY msg.created asc it work fine. But not working with desc.

Comment: db_query is like mysql_query() its my function.

Comment: How are you processing the result?

Comment: suppose you have 10 rows if you do ORDER BY msg.created asc you will get all 10 rows but with desc you will get 9 rows??? is this what happening?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Are you sure you are not just looking at your data incorrectly. I dont believe if all you change is the sort order it will loose a row. Start by **counting** the rows

Comment: @Archish yes this is the problem. Have you any idea??

Comment: Does it works same in console?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this issue is a result of the sql query, this would be a pretty big bug in mysql

Comment: If so then error in methods that receive or process the result, which are unknown to us.